# Laravel Route parameter with Angular js edit button

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5.3

I have a list of data and want to edit the data with an edit button, that time I want to send the ID to Laravel controller to fetch the data of corresponding ID. The listing was done by Angular JS.

```
 <a class="btn" href="{{URL::route('edit_repair_category')}}/[[category.id]]"></a>
```

The abouve line is redirecting to edit laravel route and its showing an error of missing parameter.

```
 Route::get('edit-repair-category/{id}', ['as' => 'edit_repair_category', 'uses' => 'RepairCategoryController@editRepairCategory']);
```

Also I want to send the ID value with encrypted format and need to decrypt on the laravel controller.

How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) directive. To make double curly braces intact in Blade template, you can use @.

```
 <a ng-repeat="category in categories" class="btn" ng-href="{{URL::route('edit_repair_category')}}/@{{ category.id }}"></a>
```

Comment: Error.....Missing required parameters for [Route: edit_repair_category] [URI: edit-repair-category/{id}].

Comment: Its a json array with multiple rows. including keys id,name, mobile etc...